# Networks of Guest OS in Hyper-V

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, ip, hyper-v

My host system is connected to a network where the IP addresses are static and need users to apply for them. Further, one IP (in use) is binded with one mac-address. On the other hand, I found that Hyper-V directly change my ethernet card into a virtual one, not like the case in VirtualBox, where there will be an extra card. Now I don't know how to configure the network in the guest OS, since there is no DHCP and no applicable static IPs (as in VirtualBox, I usually set the new virtual card as the gateway for guest OS). I've tried to configure the two OS with the same IP and mac-address, as well as set my IP address as the gateway of guest OS, but both do not work. Can anyone cast light on how to setup the network properly? Thank you~

Comment: You can't give them the same MAC address.  You are gonna run into problems during ARP resolutions. . .

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a whitepaper titled [Understanding Networking with Hyper-V](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9843).